# Computing $\text{Tor}_*^{R_G} (\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) $ for a compact Lie group $G$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $R_G$ be the representation ring of $G$ a connected, simply connected Lie group, $I_G$ the augmentation ideal and $\mathbb{Z}=R_G/I_G$. $R_G$ acts on $\mathbb{Z}$ via $V \cdot n = (\dim V ) n$. I want to (somewhat) compute $K_G^*(G * G)$ (where the star denotes the topological join). From Milnor's old paper on classifying spaces this can be reduced to a computing $\text{Tor}_*^{R_G} (\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$. I don't know a resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $R_G$, so I can't really get much beyond $\text{Tor}_1^{R_G}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})=I/I^2$.

Comment: What does $G \ast G$ denote? To me that symbol means the free product.

Comment: In any case, if $G$ is in addition assumed to be connected then $R_G$ is very close to a polynomial algebra and so you should be able to use some kind of Koszul resolution.

Comment: Yea, it's close to a polynomial algebra. It's finitely generated but the exact resolution will probably depend on $G$.

Comment: Can we say that $R_G$ being very close to polynomial, $Tor ^{R_G}(Z,Z)$ is very close to an exterior algebra?

Comment: Yea, in the case of $SU(n)$, $R_G$ is a polynomial algebra on a suitable basis of symmetric polynomials on $n$-generators, so in this case it reduces to that.